# while creating first Portlet in liferay error comes. What does it mean?

Tags: liferay, portlet

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.GlobalCommandManager.getTimestamp(GlobalCommandManager.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.GlobalCommandManager.updateTimestamps(GlobalCommandManager.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.ServerEditor.checkResourceState(ServerEditor.java:991)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.ServerEditor$ActivationListener.handleActivation(ServerEditor.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.ServerEditor$ActivationListener.shellActivated(ServerEditor.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1666)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4607)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DestroyWindow(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.destroyWidget(Control.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.destroyWidget(Shell.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close(Window.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.close(Dialog.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.close(InternalDialog.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.okPressed(Dialog.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.buttonPressed(InternalDialog.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: You forgot to add your question and give information about the version/plugins of eclipse that you're running and in what way you create this first plugin. Please make it a proper question otherwise there's no way to answer it...

Comment: 3 days and no update to the question? You must have lost interest in it. Voting to close